# Reduce the time to fetch the data from the MYSQL DB (Records in table 150,000)

Tags: mysql, yii2

Please help to sort out this isse
I have database in which i have 150,000 business records, each business record has its own business category (e.g: Bars, Pubs, Restaurant).

I am using this SQl to get Categories listing based on the visitor's location.

```
SELECT 
ROUND(6371*acos(cos(radians('52.28231599999999'))*cos(radians(bizprof.vLatitude))*cos(radians(bizprof.vLongitude)-radians('-1.584927'))+sin(radians('52.28231599999999'))*sin(radians(bizprof.vLatitude))),2) AS distance,
`bizcat`.`vCategoryName`,
`bizcat`.`iCategoryId` FROM `business_profile` `bizprof`
LEFT JOIN `users` `u` ON u.iUserId = bizprof.iUserId
AND u.tiIsProfileSet = 1
AND u.tiIsActive = 1
AND u.tiIsDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN `business_categories` `bizcat` ON bizcat.iCategoryId = bizprof.iCategoryId
GROUP BY `bizcat`.`iCategoryId`
HAVING distance >= 0 AND distance <= 10
```

This query taking too much time to render the data from the records.

Any idea on this ?

Comment: Can't help much without a [query plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html). Also tell us what the speed of the network is that you're dragging this data over, how many records result from the group by, approximately how many bytes in a record and how long it takes

Comment: sadly: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214354/does-mysql-or-mariadb-support-gis-knn-index-queries-k-nearest-neighbors/215252#215252

Comment: first thing , stop calculation in the mysql query and calculate them outside the query if possible in php, forr example `cos(radians('52.28231599999999'))`, `sin(radians('52.28231599999999'))`, `radians('-1.584927')`,

Comment: second thing analyze your tables and add appropriate indexes to the columns that are being searched, there can be huge difference in the select when correct indexes added,

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, Could you please share any good article for the better understanding of the Inexes?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [ST_Distance_Sphere(g1, g2 [, radius])](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere) and [spatial indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html)
2. Move on `AND u.tiIsProfileSet = 1 AND u.tiIsActive = 1 AND u.tiIsDeleted = 0` to `where` condition.
3. Avoid third join, fetch data from `business_categories` with another query (via relation e.g.)

Try to execute this query

```
SELECT 
ST_Distance_Sphere(Point('-1.584927','52.28231599999999'), Point(`bizprof`.`vLongitude`,`bizprof`.`vLatitude`), 6370986 ) AS `distance`,
`bizprof`.`iCategoryId`
FROM `business_profile` `bizprof`
LEFT JOIN `users` `u` ON `u`.`iUserId` = `bizprof`.`iUserId`
WHERE 1=1
    AND `u`.`tiIsProfileSet` = 1
    AND `u`.`tiIsActive` = 1
    AND `u`.`tiIsDeleted` = 0
HAVING distance >= 0 AND distance <= 10*1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the query suggestion. Could you please help me to understand why we are using this ST_Dustance_Sphere ad i am using Haversian Formula to calculate the distance and in where condition `1=1` what does it means.?  i know, i am not so much familiar as you are, but it helps me to engage my knowledge

Comment: `1=1` only for formatting, you can skip it. MySQL 5.7 introduced ST_Distance_Sphere which bit faster than raw sql Haversine Formula. See https://tighten.co/blog/a-mysql-distance-function-you-should-know-about/

Comment: Why are you suggesting to move conditions from JOIN to WHERE?

Comment: `ON` clause serves for conditions that specify how to join tables, and the `WHERE` clause restricts which rows to include in the result set.

Comment: From performance perspective filtering on JOIN should be more efficient, since it may exclude results at earlier stage of filtering. It also has different meaning in case of LEFT JOIN (which seems to be incorrect in this case).

Comment: You've also dropped `GROUP BY` from your example, but still left `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @rob006 please read the refmans https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

just some suggestion  ..
Be sure you have proper compisite indexes on

Table business_profile columns( iUserId, iCategoryId)

table  users columns (iUserId, tiIsProfileSet, tiIsActive, tiIsDeleted )

table  business_categories column (iCategoryId)

then you should not use  group by without aggregation function  (if you need  distinct result add DISTINCT clause in select )

you could also use the where (repeating di code for distance)  clause and not the having for filter the result

```
        SELECT 
        ROUND(6371*acos(cos(radians('52.28231599999999'))*cos(radians(bizprof.vLatitude))*cos(radians(bizprof.vLongitude)-radians('-1.584927'))+sin(radians('52.28231599999999'))*sin(radians(bizprof.vLatitude))),2) AS distance,
        `bizcat`.`vCategoryName`,
        `bizcat`.`iCategoryId` 
        FROM `business_profile` `bizprof`
        LEFT JOIN `users` `u` ON u.iUserId = bizprof.iUserId
            AND u.tiIsProfileSet = 1
                AND u.tiIsActive = 1
                    AND u.tiIsDeleted = 0
        LEFT JOIN `business_categories` `bizcat` ON bizcat.iCategoryId = bizprof.iCategoryId

        WHERE  ROUND(6371*acos(cos(radians('52.28231599999999'))*cos(radians(bizprof.vLatitude))*cos(radians(bizprof.vLongitude)-radians('-1.584927'))+sin(radians('52.28231599999999'))*sin(radians(bizprof.vLatitude))),2) >= 0 
        AND ROUND(6371*acos(cos(radians('52.28231599999999'))*cos(radians(bizprof.vLatitude))*cos(radians(bizprof.vLongitude)-radians('-1.584927'))+sin(radians('52.28231599999999'))*sin(radians(bizprof.vLatitude))),2) <= 10
```

Comment: as i have `HAVING distance >= 0 AND distance <= 10` but in your suggestion we are again calculation the distance and filter with the range `10`. Is this helpful to calculate the distance again on that or so ?. Please guide

Comment: The having  work on the result  .. so is executed  after he h from, where ad select clause ... the where is executed  directly over the rows ..  so for performance in better execute the filter over the rows and don't select all the rows  and filter the result  ..  In you case the use of having is just for avoid code repetition but not so good for performance .. hope is clear